# Pattern match stream retrieved from database

Tags: scala, playframework, pattern-matching

I have the following case class, which I persist to a database using Sorm:

```
case class Page(url: String)
```

When I query the database, I get this as a result:

```
Stream(Page(1,https://mywebsite.com), ?)
```

How can I pattern match this structure to extract `https://mywebsite.com`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your case class does not really match to what comes out from the DB. I'd change the case class to:

```
case class Page(id: Int, url: String)
```

And then try something like:

```
result match {
    case Page(_, website) #:: tail => website
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I try this, I get `constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : models.Page
 required: models.Page with sorm.Persisted`